# Impossible to run a.out file through Android terminal

Tags: c

I compiled and linked a file on Android (ARM). I have got a a.out file and iwant to execute it on Android (ARM) using android terminal via the command (./). It's written "operation not permitted". I even try "chmod" but it's the same thing. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running on the device or in emulator?

Comment: I am running on the device. It's a rooted Android device.

Comment: Have you checked that `chmod` results in the correct settings? Large parts of the Android filesystem are mounted in such a way that execute permission cannot be set, even by root. Also -- how did you compile and link? Did you link against libraries that actually exist? This is a problem when cross-compiling for Android because libraries are often not found in the same places as on regular Linux machines.

Comment: I used a makefile and the make command to compile and link objects files. You are right, it's surely because of the Android filesystem. My a.out file is in my sdcard. I will try to moov it from here to check it if it can work. Thank you!

Comment: It works now. I couldn't execute the a.out file because it was in sdcard. When i moov it from sdcard, i execute it successfully. I do it with a terminal emulator and i execute it in the home directory of the terminal. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found it. The problem is that we can not execute .out file on Android sdcard. So, as i am using an Android terminal emulator called Termux, i copied the a.out file in the Termux home directory or a subdirectory called "Storage" via the command line "cp". In these two directories, i successfully execute the a.out file.
On Sdcard, "a.out" file only have "read" and "write" properties, not, "execute".